# Firefox DevTools (XHR) XMLHttpRequest pretty-print

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

The Firebug extension isn't being developed, so I have started use Firefox DevTools.
I have problem with unreadable request-response XML, because both strings are one-line string.[image: Firefox DevTools]

Firebug shows request-response XML nicer.
[image]

Any idea how to show pretty-print XML in Firefox DevTools?

Comment: That's why I kept using Firebug to the last possible second... switch to Google Chrome, it does that using the Preview tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DevTools don't have this feature yet (as of Firefox 51.0.1). It's requested in [bug 1247392](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1247392), though.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not available in Firefox, I'd recomment you switching to **Google Chrome** and use the **Preview** tab under the Response section to get pretty-printed XML responses.